# Erro na matriz 3x3

Tags: java, matriz, netbeans

Estou com dificuldades em um código java. Estou tentando fazer um código a qual gera uma matriz 3x3. fiz um código a qual a primeira vista funciona tudo Okay.

matriz3x3

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
        char[][] ch = {{'2','1','9'}, {'4','8','0'},{'7','5','3'}};

for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ch[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print("ch["+i+"]["+j+"] = "+ch[i][j]+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}}
```

porem ao tenta colocar 2 números no campo a qual vai preencher a matriz, por exemplo

matriz 3x3

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
        char[][] ch = {{'20','10','90'}, {'40','80','01'},{'70','50','30'}};

for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ch[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print("ch["+i+"]["+j+"] = "+ch[i][j]+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}}
```

da um grande erro e não funciona mais o código, estou procurando meu erro, porem sou novato em Java e peço pela ajuda de vcs. Os erros que aparece são:
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)

Comment: Que erro? Adicione a pilha de erros na pergunta.

Comment: O erro que ocorre é que o código simplesmente não funciona mais, se colocar igual ao primeiro codigo que coloquei ali, vai gerar a matriz e tudo, porem quando coloco igual o do segundo a matriz nem gerar mais. .

Comment: editei e coloquei os erros acima

Comment: Não está claro seu problema. Você diz que da erro ao "2 números no campo" mas seu código apenas lista os elementos do array. Que campo? Edite a pergunta e forneça um código que seja codizente ao problema, pois o código não tem o problema que você diz enfrentar.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você usa o tipo `char` você só pode usar um caractere, como por exemplo, 1, 2, 3, representando entre aspas simples, `'1', '2', '3'`. Para fazer com mais caracteres você poderia usar o tipo `String`, como por exemplo,`String[] numeros = {"10", "20", "30"}`. Para fazer o mesmo com caracteres, você poderia usar outra abordagem, mais ou menos isso: `char[][] numeros = {{'1', '0'}, {'2', '0'}, {'3', '0'}}`, onde cada linha representa um número.

Fazendo como String ficaria assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here
        String[][] ch = {{"20","10","90"}, {"40","80","01"},{"70","50","30"}};

        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ch[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print("ch["+i+"]["+j+"] = "+ch[i][j]+"\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Para usar como char, é necessario um vetor de 3 dimensões, e converter um vetor de caracteres para String, usando o `valueOf`. Nessa abordagem fica assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    char[][][] ch = {
        {
            {'2', '0'},{'1', '0'},{'9', '0'}
        }, 
        {
            {'4', '0'},{'8', '0'},{'0', '1'}
        },
        {
            {'7', '0'},{'5', '0'},{'3', '0'}
        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ch[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print("ch["+i+"]["+j+"] = "+String.valueOf(ch[i][j])+"\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Entendo, agradeço pela ajuda. Por eu ser novato nessa linguagem não sabia dessa pequena diferença. agradecido